# Python dictionary initialization in CS50 course content

Tags: python, dictionary, cs50

The following code is taken from week 7 of CS50. It opens a file (favorites.csv), reads the titles of common television shows from the file, and adds the titles and counts of the titles to a dictionary. However, I don't understand why it works. At the start, the titles dictionary is initialized. Later the count is added to the dictionary if the title is in the titles dictionary. However, I can't understand why the titles dictionary includes any titles? Where were the titles from the favorites.csv file added to the dictionary? I would have thought that the "if title in titles" conditional would always be false because at this point it appears the dictionary is empty? A little embarrased to be asking this but I'm obviously not understanding this after a fair amount of time researching the issue. Thanks for any explanations offered.

```py
# Prints popularity of titles in CSV, sorted by title

import csv

# For accumulating (and later sorting) titles
titles = {}

# Open CSV file
with open("favorites.csv", "r") as file:

    # Create DictReader
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)

    # Iterate over CSV file, adding each (uppercased) title to dictionary
    for row in reader:

        # Canoncalize title
        title = row["title"].strip().upper()

        # Count title
        if title in titles:
            titles[title] += 1
        else:
            titles[title] = 1

# Print titles in sorted order
for title in sorted(titles):
    print(title, titles[title])
```

Comment: That's what the `else` branch does.  If a given `title` is not found in the `titles` dictionary, it will add it (with a value of `1`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When

```
if title in titles:
```

is `False`, the `else` branch runs:

```
titles[title] = 1
```

this adds the title to the dictionary.

Comment: Ok, thank you! It does seem a bit counterintuitive to me because I would interpret "titles[title] = 1" as "add value of 1 to the dictionary titles at key title". However, title wasn't added to the dictionary previously so there would be no location to add it to. Would it be correct to say that keys are added to a dictionary implicitly when values are added to a specified key? Sorry for these basic questions. I'm very new to coding and I want to ensure I have the fundamentals correct before moving forward.